# When does ruby release its File.write assignments?

Tags: ruby

I am writing to a file instance. While the program is still running, the file is always empty. When I check the file after the script has executed, the file has content.

```
class A
  def initialize
    @file_ref=File.new("/user/shared/ruby/ruby-example/test.html","w+")
  end
  def fill
    @file_ref.write("whatever\nwhatever\nwhatever\n")
  end
end
```

The Main script:

```
require_relative 'A'

a=A.new
a.fill

puts File.size("/user/shared/ruby/ruby-example/test.html")
```

After the `A` instance has done its job, the `puts` statement will print `"0"` as if the file is empty. Indeed it is during program execution, but if I start irb:

```
puts File.size("/user/shared/ruby/ruby-example/test.html")
# => 27

$ cat test.html
whatever
whatever
whatever
```

1. Is my code wrong?
2. Is it normal that streams are flushed only after the execution of a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Ruby (to my knowledge since version 1.9) features a one liner shortcut for simple file writes as well, flush included:

```
File.write('/path/to/file.txt', 'content')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby flushes IO buffers when you call [`IO#close`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-close) or [`IO#flush`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-flush). Since you are not calling neither `close` nor `flush` the buffers are flushed when the program terminates and the opened file descriptors are released.

Given your simple example a possible solution is:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @file_ref_name = '/user/shared/ruby/ruby-example/test.html'
  end
  def fill
    File.open(@file_ref_name, 'w+') do |file|
      file.write("whatever\nwhatever\nwhatever\n")
    end
  end

end
```

Passing a block to [`IO#open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-open) makes the opened file (the `file` variable in this example) to be closed (and therefore flushed) once the execution of the block terminates.